# How can I set one objects y rotation to another objects y rotation - Unity

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine

I am making a Portal clone and all was going well till I found a problem, after the player teleports he stays facing the direction that he was when he entered the portal... that means that, for example, if the portals are facing in a 180 degrees difference the player keeps hold of W and as soon as he's teleported he just teleports back through the other portal. I thought to fix this I could set the players y rotation to the receiver portals y rotation when he teleports but I haven't found a way to do this. I tried using Quaternions to do this and when setting the players y rotation to the portals the player was facing to the sky.

I tried simply:

```
player.rotation.y = portal.position.y
```

And got a error so then I used :

```
                player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(player.transform.x, -reciever.rotation.y, player.transform.rotation.z));
```

And then is when the player got rotated to look at the sky.
I hope I explained it well and to get an answer soon!

**Edit**: Then I tried:

```
MainCamera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(MainCamera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, reciever.transform.eulerAngles.y, MainCamera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z));
```

and that kind of worked but it gave me tons of bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set just one axis while setting a rotations. Unity uses quaternion for rotation. So you need to defines a new quaternion, get the rotation of the other object and set the x and z of the quaternion using your current objects rotation. Then set the quaternion to your object.

The other option is to use quaternion.lookrotation to make the object look in the direction you want.

Check out this tutorial on [Unity Quaternion](https://vionixstudio.com/2022/06/16/unity-quaternion-and-rotation-guide/) for code samples.